# No matter how many times I go into a Careers message it does not get marked as read

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, jobs

No matter how many times I go into a Careers message it does not get marked as read.

I have tried going into the message and leaving.

Clicking on the checkbox and then the button to mark as read, but yet it still does nothing.

---

Browser info:

> Google Chrome   33.0.1750.117 (Official Build 252094) m
>   OS  Windows

Comment: Hmmm it seems to have resolved itself.... Not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

It's good it seems to have resolved itself, but I am curious to know exactly what happened.  I checked the logs and I don't see anything there.

In the future when something like this happens, please be sure to check for js errors on the page because it's possible some bad data got in there and hosed that functionality or the request is returning some indication that something is wrong like a 404 or a redirect to the login page (we've had our woes with random logouts in the past).  Intermittent problems are the worst :(

Comment: There were no JS errors or anything. I checked. And the Ajax requests returned successfully

Comment: Thanks for the immediate followup.  Out of curiosity, did you look at the json response?  It will return an empty array if it fails to mark any messages as read.  Also did you see if the headers on the request included the thread ids?  That could just be a bug in the UI code.

Comment: Oooo it **did** return
 an empty array. I did not look at the request headers. Sorry :-

Comment: Thanks, that's something to go on.

Comment: No problem. Happy I can help in some way shape or form.